# Origine del detto "avere gli orecchi foderati di prosciutto"

Tags: idioms, phrase-origin

In un'altra delle sequenze di [questo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=EvNqzBHCdwc), nel quale si cerca di fare una rappresentazione letterale di alcuni modi di dire italiani, un ragazzo con delle fette di prosciutto nelle orecchie grida "Non ti sento!"

Cercando informazione sul modo di dire corrispondente nel [Dizionario dei Modi di Dire Hoepli](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/O/orecchio.shtml#5), ho trovato:

> **avere gli orecchi foderati di prosciutto**
>
> - Non sentire o fingere di non sentire, come se si avessero le
>   orecchie coperte da grosse fette di prosciutto che non lasciano passare i
>   suoni.

In questo [link](http://lang-8.com/607985/journals/110051010399191773446712839214677313095)  ho trovato che si possa anche dire "avere il prosciutto nelle orecchie", ma non so fino a che punto questo sia un sito autorevole.

Comunque, questo modo di dire mi è sembrato molto curioso e divertente. Qualcuno ne sa qualcosa delle sue origini?

Comment: C'è anche *avere le fette di salame sugli occhi*.

Comment: [Le origini](https://books.google.es/books?id=q00eBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT110&dq=occhi%20foderati%20di%20prosciutto&pg=PT110#v=onepage&q=occhi%20foderati%20di%20prosciutto&f=false) (nota che il dizionario è semiserio!)

Comment: @I.M.: Veramente divertente!

Comment: Può darsi che l'origine sia qualche malattia delle palpebre che assomigliasse in certo modo al prosciutto? https://books.google.es/books?id=ONcRAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA104&lpg=PA104&dq=prosciutto+occhi+malattia+palpebre&source=bl&ots=1xbLhDj9fD&sig=Pcnda2dzCkLQOkFWQpajO0yoH4E&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QwpFVeahKYbaU6nPgcAC&ved=0CBUQ6AEwBQ#v=snippet&q=prosciutto%20malattia%20palpebre&f=false E forse dagli occhi si è poi passato agli orecchi.

Answer (score 1):

Consultando [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=occhi%20foderati&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cocchi%20foderati%3B%2Cc0) il modo di dire in italiano risale alla seconda metà dell'800 e ci sono molti riferimenti a detti dialettali dell'Emilia/Romagna e della Toscana, zone famose per la produzione di salumi.

Esiste infatti la versione dialettale bolognese da cui penso derivi quella italiana:

[Avàir i ûc' fudrè d'parsótt = Avere gli occhi foderati di prosciutto.](https://speradisole.wordpress.com/lantico-dialetto-bolognese-4/)

Comment: Curioso. Precede l'esordio discografico di Ligabue.

Comment: Dunque, probabilmente degli occhi si è passato agli orecchi?

Comment: @TobiaTesan: Cosa vuoi dire?